# How to condition a component to display certain information?

Tags: reactjs

```css
const handleChecked=(e)=>{
  setForm({
    ...form,
    [e.target.name]:e.target.checked
   })

   if(e.target.name == 'lowercase'){
    showMinus(longitud)
   }
 
  }
 

  const handleSubmit =(e)=> {
    updatePassword(longitud)
    activeLetters()
    e.preventDefault();

  }
```

```html
file 1

 const ShowPass =()=>{
    let charactersLength = characters.length;
    let allChar = ''  
    for(let i = 0; i<range.current.value; i++){
    allChar += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()* charactersLength))
    }
    setPassword(allChar) 
  } 
   

  const showMinus=(minusculas)=>{
    let  allMin=''
     let minLong = minusculas.length;
    for(let i = 0; i<range.current.value; i++){
      allMin += minusculas.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()* minLong))
    }

    setMinus(allMin) 
  }
 
  
  //¿Que tipo de carcarter es?
  const activeLetters =()=>{
   let min = ''
   for(let i=0;i<characters.length;i++){
      let element = characters[i];
      
      if(element === element.toLowerCase() && element !== element.toUpperCase())
      min+=element
    }
    showMinus(min)
  }
 
  useEffect(()=>{
    getPassLength()
  },[])
 

 return(
  <>
    <div className='classHeader'>
      <ShowPassword password={password} icon={<HiOutlineClipboardList/>} />
    </div>
    <div className='longBox'>
      <p>Character Length</p>
      <input   type="range" min={1} max={16} step={1} ref={range} name="password" ></input>
      {long}
    </div>

    <CapitalLetters 
     updatePassword={ShowPass}
     showMinus={showMinus}
     activeLetters={activeLetters}
     longitud={long} />
  
  </>
 )
```

Hello everyone, I would like your help please: I am in a situation with the code, what I want to do is the following:
It is a password generator when I give it send
this generates a random password for me when I click the submit button, for this I have created an external component called showPassword that receives a prop called password So, so far so good because I manage to do that, my problem comes in the form file because I have some checkboxes, I want that when push lowercase it sends the password to the screen in only lowercase, that's where my problem is I don't know how to do it,
how do you think i should do it?

Comment: So when checkbox is clicked, you want to see password in lowercase only?

Comment: At the moment yes, I plan to put in capital letters, numbers and character. but i just want to know the way to display the results

could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

So on checkbox click use a state to see whether the ckeckbox is clicked on not. If yes there are js function to convert string to lowercase.

The toLowerCase() method converts a string to lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Create a state that will control whether the checkbox is checked or not then inside the props you can create a ternary operator that will send a lowercase if checked or a normal password if not.

```
<ShowPassword password={isChecked ? password.toLowerCase() : password} icon={<HiOutlineClipboardList/>} />
```

Hope this works!